# I can only take so many hours of cartoons without a break

Tags: meaning

> Denise turned towards the door as Judy McAden peeked inside. "I hope
>   I'm not coming at a bad time. I called the hospital, and they said you
>   both were up."
>
> Denise sat up, trying to straighten her wrinkled hospital grown. "No,
>   of course not. We're(Denise and her 4 year old kid) just watching T.V.
>   C'mon in."
>
> "Are you sure?"
>
> "Please. **I can only take so many hours of cartoons without a break.**"

I can't understand the last sentence - **I can only take so many hours of cartoons without a break.**

What is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Can you understand it literally? Or Is it that you can understand it literally but cannot understand why she said that?

Comment: Probably, Denise told this to McAden in a bantering way considering McAden nothing more than a cartoon character! She's watching TV (must be cartoons) and the *coming* of McAden is like just watching another cartoon channel! But that's just how I look

Comment: @MaulikV There's no banter here; Denise is saying she's been watching cartoons with her child for a long time, is sick of doing so, and welcomes the change.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName yes I got the meaning as a whole. But frankly, did not understand the words fitted in it. Wouldn't it be better using this - ***Please come (I deadly needed you at this moment as...) I cannot take so many hours of cartoons without a break OR I could only take these many hours of cartoons without a break*** Putting *could* and *these* would be so clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase

> I can only take so many hours of cartoons without a break.

is interpreted more literally as:

> There's a limit to the number of hours of cartoons I can tolerate watching consecutively without a break doing something else.

The word "take" means to tolerate or withstand, like in the phrase "I can't take it anymore".

And the structure "I can only [verb] so many [noun]" means something like "I can't [verb] more than a certain amount of [noun]".

In the context of this little dialogue snippet, the reason Denise says this is that she has been watching cartoons for hours on end with her four-year-old daughter, and Judy's arrival into the hospital room is a welcome change of events.

Comment: So... *I can only do so many things = I cannot do more than one thing?*

Comment: @MaulikV Not quite, it means *there is a maximum number of things I can do*. If someone very busy says this in response to a request, it means *I can't do that; I am doing too much already*.